# Loading ASPX markup from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let say I have one default.aspx page in local development but in production we have different mark up according to client requirement might be we will not use up-comming.ascx user control on client page but we using on local or using for other client. in short how can load aspx markup from database not .cs code since it is already compiled only change aspx.

Comment: We have 100+ clients we dont cahnge code for each client since it is multitanent applciation .. so what we do we create new theme page and use it directly

Comment: Ok, show some code, some sample.

Comment: page is simple think like this <asp:label id="lbl1" Text="Test1" /> for client two let say we using Text="Test2" its just POC so think if success in this its mean we can use complete diffrent aspx markeup

Comment: also refer this http://blog.bitlinkit.com/creatingcompiling-objects-dynamically/

Comment: I would be really tempted to look at MVC in this instance, but retreive the 'View' element from your datasource rather than a defined View.  If this isn't an option, you need to disassociate your ASPX / webform logic from the HTML content and handle the requests without the ViewState - of course this is so close to MVC you might as well take that approach.